# Using class instances as keys in a Typescript Map

Tags: typescript, dictionary

When gettings and setting map values, the map has to somehow know wether the keys equal another, already set key.

How do I implement equality for complex datatypes (custom classes) in Typescript? In Java I would override the equals method, is there an equivalent in typescript?

In my case I have the following class:

```js
export class Path {

    constructor(
        private readonly scope: string[],
        private readonly object: string[],
        private readonly value: string
    ) { }

    getScope(): string[] {
        return this.scope;
    }

    getObject(): string[] {
        return this.object;
    }

    getValue(): string {
        return this.value;
    }

    // @override equals(): boolean    --    ?

}
```

I want to use instances of this class as keys in a map like this:

```js
const map = new Map<Path, string>();
map.set(new Path(['hello'], ['world'], 'asdf'), 'hwa');
map.set(new Path(['see', 'you'], ['world'], 'asdf'), 'swa');

map.get(new Path(['hello'], ['world'], 'asdf')); // 'hwa'
map.get(new Path(['see', 'you'], ['world'], 'asdf')); // 'swa'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do I implement equality for complex datatypes (custom classes) in Typescript?

You can't. [`Map`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-map-objects) is something TypeScript gets from JavaScript. The JavaScript specification says `Map` uses the [`SameValueZero` operation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-samevaluezero) to determine whether keys are equal to each other. With object instances, that's `===`. That is, only the *same instance* is equal to itself, not equivalent instances. It doesn't defer to an object method like Java's collections can.

There's no built-in map-like structure that allows you to determine key equality. You can build one, but there's not one by default.