# Use class as TypeScript parameter for Map

Tags: typescript, parameters

I found some other similar questions [answered on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62871727/using-class-instances-as-keys-in-a-typescript-map), but none of them seems to match my issue. I've made a [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=288#code/C4TwDgpgBAsgwgewHYGdgCcCuBjYD0A8AKlBAB7ARIAmKUSEA7gBQB07AhugOYoBcUDkhABtALoBKKAF4AfIOHzp9JlDace-KIlQYcedAAUuHALYRK6FMVlS5UAJK6h2CEXAQbAbgCwAKH9sZDQoINMwZCpgABEOYA4ZFUZYDjACeGC9XHwCIRBZABoUtIAJIhgAGQBRABsIcyRgIqc0FzcPdJ00LGzCPNkB2WYJXwC-IN0oWPjEgG9-KCgUCwFiUgoqWlgurIMbIYg6huABMsra+qiisIiGRoEiIoBLZyRXARb4t-bIGwkBABuCCe1Bk8nmfkWiyeADM1ABCZiHS6NKAvVrfBBws7VI5RCRSdAWTDoJCjBZQ2EIm6RRrTDisAAWHBQzBpd2ABKgEKhUPZUXprGWwDZCHCtKaSWKBBxF2OzVerncvyIA2GIwpiwAvv5NaFMmjFRAYKlEvy6XEGdwLKLxRypCzpbK8Y0FRilR1VbJyZDKUaTWAhTbkfLDe6IBrfVqCv4tT7sDUWXQAIJ1dDAbkU+I8FZQZ0o4CjRYIMBaWZauZxikTbr6fDMbPWk558q4gtFEtlivKctSHlQ4CMp4oViNiyJMfAPWD4esTuJTt6wXCgipiDpoaTopr9NFGcoCQUnW+gD0J6gYHQCDwoEgAgAYpg3sAnsg5hSONRqA2uE2+Pnjj7fdR1-cdlEnY9FjPKAqz8Y9-AYZIdxFagEGwTBjlYbAiTiCA5SiZgAHJqCeAFCIkIpZhLABGAQ9AgDswAAJgEQiSyYgB9AEOBqTAIEIrVDzGIA) to work on it.

**Here is my code:**

```js
type MConstructor<T extends new(...args: any[]) => any> = new (...args: ConstructorParameters<T>) => InstanceType<T>;

const componentData = new Map<MConstructor<any>, Map<HTMLElement, InstanceType<MConstructor<any>>>>();

const Data = {
  set: <T extends MConstructor<T>>(element: HTMLElement, component: T, instance: InstanceType<T>): void => {
    if (!(element instanceof HTMLElement)) return;

    if (!componentData.has(component)) {
      componentData.set(component, new Map<HTMLElement, InstanceType<T>>());
    }

    const instanceMap = componentData.get(component) as Map<HTMLElement, InstanceType<T>>;

    instanceMap.set(element, instance);
  },
};

class Alert {
  target: HTMLElement;
  ops: {} = {};
  constructor(target: HTMLElement, ops: {} = {}) {
    this.target = target
    this.ops = ops
    Data.set<Alert>(target, Alert, this)
  }
  add(target:HTMLElement) {this.target = target}
}

new Alert(document.createElement('div'), {op1: true, op2: 'op2_value'})
```

**Here's the error:**

```
Type 'Alert' does not satisfy the constraint 'MConstructor<Alert>'.
  Type 'Alert' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: never): any'.
```

**Update**: on a closer look, seems I can actually do `Data.set(target, Alert, this)` and the error goes away, but I'm not sure it's a consistent TypeScript implementation.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like the following snippet. The thing is that classes are values and you need to get its type instead.

```js
Data.set<typeof Alert>(target, Alert, this)
```

Or even without the generic argument by letting Typescript infer it automatically:

```js
Data.set(target, Alert, this)
```